# Is there a faster method for a NSLookup than InetAddress.getByName()?

Tags: java

My goal is to check a big list of domains as fast as possible. The method `InetAddress.getByName()` seems to be a little bit slow for me. In PHP there's `gethostbyname('www.example.com')`which seems to work faster. Is there an equivalent in Java which is faster? or is there a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLookups take time because of the network infrastructure, but you can make the check in paralell. Write a thread that make the lookup and run multiple instances of it in paralell.

```
class LookUpThread implements Runnable {
String name;
public LookUpThread() {

}

public LookUpThread(String Name) {
    this.name = Name;
}

public void run() 
{
    try 
    {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(this.name);
        System.out.println(address.getHostAddress());
    } 
    catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + E.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

And in you main:

```
String[] adds = new String[]{"example.com", "example.com"};
for(int i = 0; i < adds.length; i++)
    new LookUpThread(adds[i]).run();
```